# Another mid level math question about %.

Tags: percentages

$A = 1000, B = 0.6$

$Y \times B = A  ; (? \times 0.6 = 1000)$

Need to find $Y$ every time I change $A$ or $B$. How do i ask a calculator to do that (: ?

(I managed to reverse engineer a way from another answer by René Richter - which is)

$(1 / B) \times A$

Any other obvious ways to calculate this that I'm missing?
Yes i know its probably pitiful, but a headache and silly math skills only get so far ...

Thx in advance.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure what you are trying to accomplish here:

if $$Y = A/B $$

Then if you change B, simply divide it by your value of A to find Y.

Similarly if you change A, you would follow the same process.

Comment: yes that "$Y=A/B$" was "the alternative way to find $Y$" that i looking for. ...Just expanding my low level math, bit by bit. thank you. It definitely wouldn't have occurred to me.

Comment: @helena4 no problem

Comment: @helena4 Note that this isn't just some method that happens to work, *this is what division is for*. The definition of $a/b$ is "what do I need to multiply $b$ by to get $a$".

Comment: @JackM ...Well thats what happens when you got a boring teacher. They tell you to jump and how high, but most of them forget to let us in on the "why the hell are we jumping?!"